# subclasses of pandas' object work differently from subclass of other object?

Tags: python, subclass, pandas, series

I am trying to create a subclass of a Pandas data structure to substitute, in my code, a subclass of a **`dict`** with a subclass of a **`Series`**, I don't understand why this example code doesn't work

```
from pandas import Series    

class Support(Series):
    def supportMethod1(self):
        print 'I am support method 1'       
    def supportMethod2(self):
        print 'I am support method 2'

class Compute(object):
    supp=None        
    def test(self):
        self.supp()  

class Config(object):
    supp=None        
    @classmethod
    def initializeConfig(cls):
        cls.supp=Support()
    @classmethod
    def setConfig1(cls):
        Compute.supp=cls.supp.supportMethod1
    @classmethod
    def setConfig2(cls):
        Compute.supp=cls.supp.supportMethod2            

Config.initializeConfig()

Config.setConfig1()    
c1=Compute()
c1.test()

Config.setConfig2()    
c1.test()
```

Probably it is not the best method to change the configuration of some objects, anyway I found this usefull in my code and most of all I want to understand why with **dict** instead of **series** it works as I expect.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Current Answer (Pandas >= 0.13)

An internal refactor in Pandas 0.13 drastically simplified subclassing. Pandas `Series` can now be subclassed like any other Python object:

```
class MySeries(pd.Series):
    def my_method(self):
        return "my_method"
```

## Legacy Answer (Pandas <= 0.12)

The problem is that Series uses `__new__` which is ensuring that a Series object is instantiated.

You can modify your class like so:

```
class Support(pd.Series):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        arr = Series.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return arr.view(Support)

    def supportMethod1(self):
        print 'I am support method 1'       
    def supportMethod2(self):
        print 'I am support method 2'
```

However, it's probably best to do a has-a instead of a is-a. Or monkey patch the Series object. The reason is that you will often lose your subclass while using pandas due to the nature of it's data storage. Something as simple as

```
s.ix[:5] 
s.cumsum()
```

Will return a Series object instead of your subclass. Internally, the data is stored in contiguous arrays and optimized for speed. The data is only boxed with a class when needed and those classes are hardcoded. Plus, it's not immediately obvious if something like `s.ix[:5]` should return the same subclass. That would depend on the semantics of your subclass and what metadata is attached to it.

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/3366583/subclassing%20pandas%20objects.ipynb has some notes.

Comment: It works! But you are right... probably it was not the best choice to implement a subclass!
Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

`Support()` returns a `Series` object.

On subclassing of Series and DataFrame see also: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/60

```
In [16]: class MyDict(dict):
   ....:     pass
   ....:

In [17]: md = MyDict()

In [18]: type(md)
Out[18]: __main__.MyDict

In [21]: class MySeries(Series):
   ....:     pass
   ....:

In [22]: ms = MySeries()

In [23]: type(ms)
Out[23]: pandas.core.series.Series
```