# In python, why can't I inherit pandas.Series in a simple manner?

Tags: python, inheritance, pandas, series

I would like to create a new class which inherits from pandas.Series. I usually don't have any problem creating a child class in python, but I am having problems in this case.

Here is a simple inheritance scheme:

```
class Test(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "new Test"
        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    def __init__(self):
        print "init Test"

class A(Test):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "new A"
        return Test.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    def __init__(self):
        print "init A"

print "creating an instance of A"
a = A()
print "type: ", type(a)
```

which outputs:

```
creating an instance of A
new A
new Test
init A
type:  <class '__main__.A'>
```

now lets try it with a Series:

```
import pandas as pd
class subSeries(pd.Series):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print "new subSeries"
        return pd.Series.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self):
        print "init subSeries"
print "creating an instance of subSeries"
s = subSeries()
print "type: ", type(s)
```

and we get:

```
creating an instance of subSeries
new subSeries
type:  <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

why is `s` a Series and not a subSeries?

Comment: can this post be helpful, maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979194/subclasses-of-pandas-object-work-differently-from-subclass-of-other-object

Comment: Actually, this is very helpful.  But I still wonder why does it act this way?

Comment: There are reasons for using `__new__`, but simply Series inherits from numpy.ndarray which enforces this behavior.

Comment: Someone want to post this as the answer to close out the question?

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue tracked on this topic on the pandas github site:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/60

I ran into this issue myself while subclassing Series for a spectral library data format (indexed by wavelength). It was pretty rough, lots of monkey patching and writing methods that called the Series method explicitly but just swapped it for my Spectrum class before returning. I had to define some logic in **new** and some in **init**.

It apparently has to do with a mix of Cython and Python and the numpy C API as well as inconsistent use of the _constructor() method. I haven't checked in on it recently, though. I know there was a change from ndarray to a different intermediate class, NDFrame, as the Dataframe and Series parent class (or maybe it's still in process).